# Calculation not correct

Tags: mysql

The precedence is not correct in this formula.

What I want to do is calculate a subtotal **without the discount**. Can someone tell me where I'm making my mistake?

```
((`p`.`tax_state` + `p`.`tax_fed`) / 100) * 
    ((`p`.`price` * `op`.`quantity`) -
        ((`p`.`price` * `op`.`quantity`) * `op`.`discount`))
```

Comment: If you want to calculate subtotal without tax, why does your formula include the words "tax_state" and "tax_fed"?

Comment: I wanted to include the tax and discounts, then back them out so as to make sure I have the correct totals.

Comment: Is `discount` stored at a number (`25`)? or a fraction (`.75`).

Comment: The discount is stored as a fraction. eg: `.05`

Comment: I just reread the question, if you want to get the subtotal **without tax and discount**, whats wrong with just `SELECT (p.price * op.quantity)`?

Comment: Actually, I need to edit my post because that formula should be returning just the tax. I was to deduct the discount.

Answer (score 0):

Given that the tax rates are stored as percentages, but the discount is stored as a fraction (so much for consistency!), and noting that the backticks really aren't necessary and are very undesirable for readability, then...

```
(p.price * op.quantity) AS gross_price_exc_tax,
(p.price * op.quantity) * (1 + (p.tax_state + p.tax_fed) / 100)
                        AS gross_price_inc_tax,
(p.price * op.quantity) * (1 + (p.tax_state + p.tax_fed) / 100) *
      (1 - op.discount) AS net_price_inc_tax,
...
```

These are pretty similar to what you wrote, so you need to demonstrate what you have as input data, and what you are getting as results, and you should be able to explain what you expected as a contrast to what you got.  Is there any danger that MySQL is treating some part of the expression(s) as an integer when you expect it to be a floating point value?

You should also do as I did, and build up your set of expressions one piece at a time, analyzing the results each time.  This can help you find problems quicker.  For example, I could add:

```
(1 + (p.tax_state + p.tax_fed) / 100) AS tax_multiplier
```

If that showed up as 1 instead of 1.125 or whatever the correct fraction is, then I'd know to review that expression, probably adding decimal points to the two constants.